# How to get a "class" out of proxy?

Tags: class, clojure, proxy, gen-class

I want to generate a class (not an object) via [`proxy`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/proxy), and the class will be instantiated later.

The examples I have found of Clojure's proxy method seem to largely deal with the most common java inner class scenario, i.e., when we are only defining a class because we want to create an instance of it.

In my case, I want to define a true class - one which can be loaded later on.. But I'd like to define it without having to compile it using the complexity of `gen-class`.

Would that be possible at all?  Or is [`gen-class`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/gen-class) a requirement?

Answer (score 1):

If you define a [Clojure Protocol](http://clojure.org/protocols) and then create a class that implements that protocol you can then create instances later that are simple classes.

```
 (defprotocol myProtocol
  (doStuff [this x y])
  (getA [this])
  (setA [this n]))

(deftype Foo [ ^:unsynchronized-mutable a]
  myProtocol
  (doStuff [this x y] (+ x y a))
  (getA [this] a)
  (setA [this n] (set! a n)))

(def a (Foo. 42))

user> (.getA a)
42
user> (.setA a 41)
41
user> (.getA a)
41
user> (.doStuff a 3 4)
48
user> (class a)
user.Foo
```

The class that gets created goes in a package with the same name as the namespace that called `deftype`